# dbms_lob.append cannot append a string to a bind variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus, oracle19c

Would someone please point out what I am missing here?

Below is a minimal example:

```sql
var c clob
exec dbms_lob.append(:c, 'test')
print c
```

It produces this error:

```
BEGIN dbms_lob.append(:c, 'test'); END;
Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: invalid LOB locator specified: ORA-22275
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 656
ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

I checked the [Oracle docs about bind variables](https://docs.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=db19&id=GUID-B4A0DAA3-B6E0-42F7-89B0-EF9C41F02FA3), which says

> When you execute a VARIABLE ... CLOB or NCLOB command, SQL*Plus associates a LOB locator with the bind variable.

So I don't think it is because there is no locator allocated to `c`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'create' the lob before using it like this.

```
SQL> var c clob
SQL> exec dbms_lob.createtemporary(:c,false);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec dbms_lob.append(:c,'acb');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :c

C
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
acb
```